# How do I build mastery pages for general use?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I first started playing LoL I read quite a few guides on Mobafire, and made my mastery pages based on those. I managed to make up to twenty (the current max) mastery pages, and now I can't make anymore. So clearly I need to start making my mastery pages for more generalized use (jungle/tank/etc), so how should I begin to do that, and how should I categorize?

[image: Mastery Pages]

Comment: Remove the ones you don't use, then generalize AD with def, ad with utility, ap with def and so one... most of the generalized once can be used with different champions. The rest you need to create seperate pages for.

Comment: @Lyrion I've kind of had my hand held thanks to guides, so I'm not sure. Do you have any examples or starting points for me? please.

Comment: You should probably have a page for each situation, so Top, Jungle, Mid, ADC and Support.

Comment: @Scootaloo Looking at your Annie build, you see the 21 points in offense is always the standard 21 offense to take for an AP champion. The other 9 might be distributed in defense or utility, those 9 points will change depending on if you want the champ to be more tanky or to have some more mana regen. Depending on your play style ect... there are loads of builds, instead of of just following a guide, read all the skills first and think about what you want to do.

Comment: @Lyrion Ok thanks. So [for example] if I wanted to build Annie and make her more beefy then I'd focus more points in defense too?

Comment: @Scootaloo You would leave alone the 21 in offense, and instead of going 9 in utility you place the 9 points in defense. Mostly the extra magic resist and armor could help you. Now you have the 21/9/0 Ap def build. Then you place the 9 points from defense to the ultility tree, here you will probably take meditation or move speed or the one that gives mana depending on what you find best here. And now you already have 2 mastery pages 1 for ap with more def, and 1 for ap with more ultility.

Comment: Exactly, those small changes can be done during champion select. Get to know the masteries so you can quickly spend those points after you selected a champion. There should be plenty of time left to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to this question, and I can't make up a special answer for you either, since we know very little about the way you play.

All I can do is give you a few pointers:

- Mobafire is a poor reference when it comes to champion builds. The most trustworthy source at the moment is [ProBuilds.net](http://www.probuilds.net/) (a website which automatically saves masteries, runes, items and spell order data used by pro players in their most recent public games). And even so, you shouldn't trust them blindly. **An average mastery page you made yourself is very likely to be better for you than a pro player's one you don't understand. Think for yourself!**
- If you can't figure out what *generic* mastery pages should look like, [this is an okay start](http://www.nerfplz.com/2012/12/season-3-mastery-guide-which-masteries.html). But you **must** understand the reasoning behind them, because you **will** eventually have to optimize them according to your playing style and preferences.
- Players who are specialized in a role (top, mid, jungler...) are likely to spend 10+ mastery pages on this specific role, so they will always have an optimized mastery page ready for every situation.

Feel free to leave a comment if anything remains obscure to you, and I will edit this answer.

Comment: It might be worth noting that even pro players often modify their mastery pages in champ select to accommodate the composition of the opposing team or their own. The stored ones are more just general guidelines for a role

Comment: I guess they do that in championships, yes. But in everyday gaming I tend to be lazy, or to forget undoing previous changes, or I simply don't have the time to edit my page before the game starts (and I suppose they feel the same). Building solid masteries setups even before changes is mandatory anyway.

Comment: "An average mastery page you made yourself is very likely to be better for you than a pro player's one you don't understand. Think for yourself!" **Yes! That!** Get a general idea of what's good, and then figure out what's good for your play style.